# Add integer to name

Tags: c#, winforms, integer, tabcontrol

I am working on adding a a `TabPage` to my program, and it needs to have a number in its name.

You can make new tabs like this:

```
TabPage tabname = new TabPage();
```

I am trying to make a tabpage like that, but it needs to contain an integer value like this:

```
int tabCount = 2;
TabPage tab + tabCount = new Tabpage();
```

I tried a work around, and did this:

```
int tabCount = 2;
string tabName;
tabName = "tab" + tabs;
TabPage tabName = new TabPage();
```

Where the name is supposed to be the string name, but I can't even get that to work, and it is giving me errors.
Is there any way you can put an integer inside of a name, or make the name the string name?

Comment: Value comes at run-time. Variable name is defined at compile time! BTW **WHY** you need it? Just create tab page and assign Name property. With that you'll search for it.

Comment: I have a AddTab `Button` in my `Form` and I need to be able to add as many tabs as I want. In order to do that, I have my integer go up a value every time I add a tab, and then I can access them whenever I need to.

Comment: What you really want is a list of tabs. This question may be an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: That is not what I was doing at all. If I don't post what I tried, you are the kind of people to downvote my question and post "Tell us what you tried". So I posted what I tried, and I was still asking how to fix my first problem. In my question at the bottom, this is what I said " Is there any way you can put an integer inside of a name, or make the name the string name?" Not at all a XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how variable names work I will try to explain with an example here.

```
List<TabPage> tabPages = new List<TabPage>(); // Creates a list of tabPage items

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) // A loop to create 10 tab pages
{
    // The variable name "tabPage" is for internal code use.
    // The variable name is one used in the scope of one loop.
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();

    // Setting the tabPage.Name property is how you give a name to this object
    // Here the Name of the tab will be "tab0" through to "tab9" 
    tabPage.Name = "tab" + x;

    tabPages.Add(tabPage); // Add the current tabPage to the list
}

// Now that we have a list of TabPage Items we can search the list
foreach(TabPage tab in tabPages)
{
    if(tab.Name.Equals("tab5"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tab 5 was found");
    }
}
```

I will add that you will need to assign these tabs to a panel/container. Then in future you can search the child elements of said panel/container and check the Name properties of each element. Like the list example above.

Comment: @Dozer789 sorry System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine

Comment: That is a little better. ;-)

Comment: His was the first answer, and that was all I need. If I ever need anything more complex, I might go with yours, but right now that was all I needed.

Comment: @Dozer789 **First** doesn't always mean **best**.. also I started my answer before he posted his. I just took longer to write mine :)

Comment: Ok. I don't need anything more than that, but for your answer, I gave you an upvote. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Name property of TabPage.

```
TabPage tab = new TabPage();
tab.Name = "tab" + tabs;//"tab"+tabIndex maybe more meaningful
```

Comment: Wow, very simple. I thought I tried that but I guess not. Thanks! I'll accept when I can.

Comment: So am I! ;-) Hopefully I wont have any more problems.